# SSRS throws "Invalid or Expired Session" for one specific user on one specific report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I have a report named "comments". If I rename this report, the user in question can access it. If I load the report from another user, that user can access it.

When the specific combination of the one single user and the one report interact, I get the loading screen for a long time, then an ERROR 500 page with this message:

The report execution 02nflxieo0f0tt55ptcdw045 has expired or cannot be found. (rsExecutionNotFound)

(I always get that report execution code)

and I get the following in my log file:

```
library!ReportServer_0-1!e94!11/15/2018-15:52:12:: i INFO: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/Reports/comments). User: DANIE01-SSRS\Administrator.
library!ReportServer_0-1!e94!11/15/2018-15:52:12:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: , An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database.;
session!ReportServer_0-1!e94!11/15/2018-15:52:12:: e ERROR: Error in getting session data: Invalid or Expired Session: 02nflxieo0f0tt55ptcdw045
session!ReportServer_0-1!e94!11/15/2018-15:52:12:: i INFO: LoadSnapshot: Item with session: 02nflxieo0f0tt55ptcdw045, reportPath: , userName: DANIE01-SSRS\Administrator not found in the database
library!ReportServer_0-1!e94!11/15/2018-15:52:12:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ExecutionNotFoundException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ExecutionNotFoundException: The report execution 02nflxieo0f0tt55ptcdw045 has expired or cannot be found.;
```

So my guess is that, for some reason, SSRS keeps trying to continue this session even though it's dead, and it's not getting cleared from the report service database.

Any idea how I could possibly fix this? I have tried restarting everything.

Answer (score 2):

Clearing the browser cache fixed it.

Interestingly this simple solution only occurred to me immediately after I posted this.